# Posting large form to php file

Tags: php, mysql, forms, userfrosting

[image: A very large form]

I have a form that has about 100 inputs on it that I am sending to a php file to submit the data. I am trying to find the best way to code the submit file, where I would not have to code each post value.

```html
<?php
/*

  UserFrosting Version: 0.2.0
  By Alex Weissman
  Copyright (c) 2014

  Based on the UserCake user management system, v2.0.2.
  Copyright (c) 2009-2012

  UserFrosting, like UserCake, is 100% free and open-source.

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files (the 'Software'), to deal
  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED 'AS IS', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  THE SOFTWARE.

 */

require_once("../models/config.php");

if (!securePage(__FILE__)) {
    // Forward to index page
    addAlert("danger", "Whoops, looks like you don't have permission to view that page.");
    header("Location: 404.php");
    exit();
}

setReferralPage(getAbsoluteDocumentPath(__FILE__));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Life Medical Response Dashboard</title>

        <?php require_once("includes.php"); ?>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            </nav>

            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id='display-alerts' class="col-lg-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Dashboard <small>User Overview</small></h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</li>
                        </ol>

                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i> Options </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="add_stock.php" role="button">Request Stock</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="remove_stock.php" role="button">Remove Stock</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                          
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> Supplies </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                            Date
                        </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                            Station
                        </div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                                      <form action="supply_request_submit.php">
                                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <select class="form-control">
                                 <?php
                                                include 'connection.php';
                                                $station = "SELECT * FROM stations";
                                                $result_station = mysql_query($station);
                                                while ($row_station = mysql_fetch_array($result_station)) {
                                                    ;
                                                    ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_station['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row_station['station'] ?></option>
                                                <?php }?>
                                
                            </select>

                        </div>


                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                    Airway Supplies
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php
                                                include 'connection.php';
                                                $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 2";
                                                $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                    ;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply">"></label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" > 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply">Amount (in dollars)</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" > 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>


                                                <?php } ?>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                                    Trauma Equipment
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php
                                                include 'connection.php';
                                                $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 3";
                                                $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                    ;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply">Amount (in dollars)</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>"></label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>


                                                <?php } ?>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                    IV / Medication Administration
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php
                                                include 'connection.php';
                                                $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 4";
                                                $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                    ;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>


                                                <?php } ?>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                                        Miscellaneous Items
                                                    </a>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <?php
                                                    include 'connection.php';
                                                    $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 5";
                                                    $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                    while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                        ;
                                                        ?>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>


                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
                                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                                                            Vital Sign Equipment
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <?php
                                                        include 'connection.php';
                                                        $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 6";
                                                        $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                        while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                            ;
                                                            ?>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"></label>
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>


                                                        <?php } ?>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>



                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
                                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                                                            Splinting Equipment
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <?php
                                                        include 'connection.php';
                                                        $airway_supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies WHERE category = 7";
                                                        $result_airway_supplies = mysql_query($airway_supplies);
                                                        while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) {
                                                            ;
                                                            ?>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>"></label>
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                                <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>"></label>
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">Request</div>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply"> 
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>


                                                        <?php } ?>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>



                                            </div>
                                        </div>





                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" form="supply"></div>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.row -->

                    </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->

                </div><!-- /#wrapper -->

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        alertWidget('display-alerts');

                        // Load the header
                        $('.navbar').load('header.php', function () {
                            $('.navitem-dashboard').addClass('active');
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

```html
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];
$station = $_POST['station']
?>
<?php

include 'connection.php';
$supplies = "SELECT * FROM supplies";
$result_supplies = mysql_query($supplies);
while ($row_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_supplies)) {
    ;

}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain exact what is your issue?

Comment: Just as a note, it looks like you're using a very outdated version of UF.  If possible, I highly recommend updating to v0.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the "name" attributes on form variables. (Check your markup, you had a div missing - I may have misplaced it).

```
while ($row_airway_supplies = mysql_fetch_array($result_airway_supplies)) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?php echo $row_airway_supplies['name'] ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="sr-only" for="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply">"></label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Stock</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" name="stock[<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>]"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="sr-only" for="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply">Amount (in dollars)</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">Request
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" stock[<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>]> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Pay attention to the following :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" name="stock[<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>]">
<!-- and -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>" form="supply" stock[<?php echo $row_airway_supplies['id'] ?>]>
```

By adding the name = stock[...] attributes, the form variables will be posted to your submit handler as arrays. You can then handle them as follows :

```
foreach ($_FORM['stock'] as $supplies_id => $supplies_values {
   if (!empty($supplies_values) {
       echo "You submitted {$supplies_values} for id {$supplies_id}.<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore null values. I'm considering an if statement

Comment: See my update in the last code segment (if (!empty())) .

Answer (score 0):

In order not to get each `$_POST[]` value individually, you can use `extract()`:

```
extract($_POST);
```

It will turn each `$_POST` key into a variable.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$station = $_POST['station'];
```

`extract` will generate both `$date` and `$station` automatically. (And all of the other keys)

Check out this [manual of the extract function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php)

I gotta admit I'm surprised that this function is not much explored, considering it's level of amazingness.

Comment: Some might find polluting name spaces with unknown variables to be less than amazing.

Comment: As long as you use it carefully, you won't face any problems.

Comment: You can't use it carefully. Users can post anything, and you have no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep same name of table fields name and form input field name. Write a function :

```
/**
         * @param array $fields_values
         * @param string $table
         * @return string
         */
        function _insertQuery(array $fields_values, $table) {
            $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($fields_values));
            $values = implode(', ', array_values($fields_values));
            return $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$values})";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Jquery`'s `serialize` method, it returns a string for posting based on your form, then you can submit the form using `AJAX`

e.g. :

`<form id="form1>
     <input name="username" value="hi">
     <input name="password" value="1">
 </form>`

then on jquery:

`var data = $('#form1').serialize();`

data now should be:

`username=hi&password=1`

(NOTE: POST name is based of the input's name on the HTML markup)

then post this on your php script using AJAX:

`$.ajax({
    url: "yourphpscripthere.php", //<-- PHP Script where you want to post your data
    type: "POST",
    data: data, //<-- this is the posted string
    success: function(data){
         //do something when request is finished.
    }
});`

then on your `yourphpscripthere.php`

you can do it like:

```
$fields = array();
 $values = array();
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
      array_push($fields, $key);
      array_push($values, $value);
 }

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (".implode(", ", $fields).") VALUES (".implode(", ", $values).")"

mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: name of the input form in the HTML markup should be same at the fields